# Do mega-journals (e.g. Scientific Reports, BMJ Open, Sage Open, ...) have longer peer review durations?

Tags: publications, peer-review, publishers, open-access

We recently discussed mega journals (PLOS One, Scientific Reports, SAGE OPEN, BMJ OPEN, ...) in our group. One member argued that said journals have longer peer review and processing times than field-specific journals. He argued that said journals require more time to find field-specific editors and peer reviewers. In addition, said journals receive large amounts of manuscripts.
Would you agree on this argument?

Comment: I do not have too many data points (two with Scientific Reports, to be precise), but in these cases there was nothing special about processing and review times.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is allowed to post links to other homepages but there are several databases of review reports that undermine the above mentioned hypothesis.

Comment: @Dr.M Seems you have your answer, then.

Comment: @BryanKrause - well I personally think that said databases are susceptible to bias (e.g. like product reviews on Amazon) with people being more likely to report their negative experiences...

Answer (score 1):

Why speculate? The average review times are Google-able, e.g. [here's](https://www.nature.com/nature-portfolio/about/journal-metrics) a table with the data for the *Nature* portfolio. It's a long list, so only screenshotting the top portion of the table:

[image]

And here is the data for *Scientific Reports*:

[image]

Someone better at statistics than me could check if the hypothesis that *Scientific Reports* has longer peer review times is true. Me, I'd just say it doesn't look like there's special about it.

Comment: @ Allure : Thank you! I was unaware of this.